# How to make html datalist compatible on IOS which is present on my visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery, html5

`<apex:inputText list="{!listOfStringElements}" id="userInput" onChange="alert(this.value);"></apex:inputText>`

In the above code the list attribute generates a dynamic datalist but the datlaist does not work on on IOS devices . What should I do to make it work on IOS.